# data.key is undefined: how to parse json data

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I want to draw rectangles in proportion to the size of cities. But I keep getting stuck with parsing the data. I can take out the keys of the data, but when I use the keys by doing data.key it gives me "undefined". I think the problem lays in the fact that the keys are strings, because data.Amsterdam works fine. How can I solve this problem?

```
var current = "Amsterdam"

var g = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", 1000)
    .attr("height", 1000)
    .append("svg:g");

d3.json("data_2014.json", function (error, data) {
    for (var key in data) {
        console.log(data.key)
        g.append("rect")
            .attr("width", data.key.a_opp_ha/100)
            .attr("height", data.key.a_opp_ha/100)
            .attr("x", 0)
            .attr("y", 0)
            .attr("fill", function (ding) {
                if (key === current) {
                    return "blue";
                } else {
                    return "none"};
                }
            })
            .attr("stroke", "teal");
    }
})
```

example data:

```
{
  "'s-Gravenhage": { "a_opp_ha": "9811", "a_pau": "178360", "ste_oad": "4755" },
  "Amsterdam": { "a_opp_ha": "21949", "a_pau": "230675", "ste_oad": "6096" }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `data[key]` expression instead of `data.key`.